# Convert to DateTime "05:10:15D+0"

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format, reuters

I'm having trouble Converting `"05:10:15D+0"` to `DateTime`. Reuters has the datatype as "bftime" and time is in GMT/UTC.

I don't want to substring it as I have Multiple Market Data Providers which send this value as *only* Date if the markets have not opened up.

Following is the way I'm trying to convert.ToDateTime

```
MDLastTick =  Convert.ToDateTime(LastTick);
```

Exception:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 8.

Comment: Did you specify the Culture?

Comment: What is the CumulativeUpdate ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: The object holding the data he wants to convert...

Comment: Do you have any link to documentation for the `bftime` format? Or at least explain what it is composed of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regexp to just grab out the time component: `\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}` (Or just use the first 8 characters as a substring) - and then `datetime.parse` the matching time. You know it's always UTC so you can ignore the D+0.

This is however just a time, not a datetime.

Comment: Thanks :) Initial testing works very well for this approach. Testing more

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not a datetime as it's missing the date part. You only have time, so consider using `TimeSpan.Parse`.

Comment: Thanks, however how do I Parse it in case I get DateTime ?

Comment: @Rauld - If there is no date component, you can't get a `DateTime`. There is no way around this. You can make up a date and use that, however.

Comment: Cant Parse this as TimeSpan either    string s = "05:10:15D+0";
      TimeSpan s1 = TimeSpan.Parse("05:10:15D+0"); Exception :String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.

Comment: Reuters sends it own format "bftime" - researching it now, Bloomberg would send a date if trading has not started.